# Logging Request in Laravel RouteCollection match

Tags: exception, laravel

So I'm getting a `NotFoundHttpException` in my laravel log file, but irritatingly, the exception doesn't particularly pass along too much information as to what exactly happened.  In particular, I'm hoping to send the `$request` variable into the log when the exception is called - any idea on how to do this?
Calling `Log::error(print_r($request))` just mentions that `Illuminate\Routing\Log` is not found.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
\Log::error(...);
```

It's a `namespacing` problem.